# Обрезка строки SQL от символа до символа

Tags: mysql

Нужно чтобы запрос обрезал строки в столбце
Есть столбец comments в котором данные с разным кол-вом символов но есть повторяющиеся точка с запитой пример 9853;24646;1001220;
Мне нужны последние цифры 1001220, в моей версии SQL пробывал substr index но не работает. Кто что может подсказать

Comment: *пробывал substr index но не работает* Не работать - не может. Дать результат, отличный от ожидаемого - запросто, если ошибся в параметрах. *нужны последние цифры* count=-1. А если, как в примере, на хвосте лишний разделитель - предварительно тримануть его.

Comment: Я как чайник даже не понял значения слова "тримануть". Всю информацию беру из инета.

Comment: Запрос писал такой SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(comments, ";", -2);

Comment: на что выдает ошибку invalid identifier

Comment: *не понял значения слова "тримануть"* [TRIM() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim). *Запрос писал такой* [String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).

Answer (score 1):

С утра со свежей головой нашел решение моей проблемы.

```
select rtrim(substr(comments, instr(comments,';', -1, 2) +1), ';')
from orders
where id = 2747408
```